# cant get count of the data properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a model template which hasmany themes.I want to show the list of templates with count of themes.I am using this

```
$this->Template->bindModel(
    array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'TemplateTheme' => array(
                'className' => 'TemplateTheme',
                'fields'    => 'count(TemplateTheme.id) AS themes'
            )
        )
    ), false ...
```

it gives me 2 templates.But it gives me all the 3 themes count in the first template whereas 2 themes belongs to template 1 and the third theme belongs to template 2
in the query it is using id IN(template_id1,template_id2)
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I recommend using virtual fields for this - see the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a common mistake, you are counting everyrow each time since you are not using group by, you should do is group by  Template.id  when you do your search. Butttttttt.... has many wont do a join :( so you have to force it a littleor use something like linkable component

example

```
$join = array(
    array('table' => 'templateThemes',
        'alias' => 'TemplateTheme',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Template.id = TemplateTheme.Template_id',
        )
    )
);
$fields = array('Template.id','count(TemplateTheme.id) AS themes');
$this->Template->find('all', array('fields'=>$fields, 'joins'=>$join', $group =>array('Template.id')));
```

You may also do it in reverse since belongsTo does the join something like this

in your model (it is always recommended to put it static in your model unless is not a normal association)

```
var belongsTo = array(
        'Template'=> array(
             'classname' => 'Template',
             'foreign_key' => 'template_id'
         );
```

and in controller

```
$fields = array('Template.id','count(TemplateTheme.id) AS themes');
$this->Template->find('all', array('fields'=>$fields, $group =>array('Template.id')));
```

Hope this helps you, if not just comment